# What is the probability of getting 2 people out of 10 with the same birthday?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If you have 10 people, what is the probability of 2 (or more) people having the same birthday?

Comment: Hint: How many days have a year?

Answer (score 8):

**HINT**

Well, it's very easy to see the probability that no pair shares the same birthday.

Say there are 2 people. Then one has a birthday, and the probability that the other person doesn't have that birthday is $364/365$, representing every day of the year besides the first (assuming all days are equally likely and that there is no such thing as a leap year birthday). If there is a third person, then the probability that he doesn't share a birthday with the other two is...

Continuing to 10 people, you get that...

Answer (score 2):

I think of it this way. You have to pick a number between 1 and 365 (365 days in a year). The number you pick corresponds to a day (birth day).

Based on the above consideration,this how we tackle your problem

1>What is the probability that none of them have the same birthday?

2>The opposite of what you get above is the probability of 2 people or more having the same birthday.

If you have to pick a number between 1-365 ten times, the chance that **none of them are same** is calculated as

number of ways to pick ten different numbers divided by
total number of ways to pick ten numbers

(desirable outcomes/ possible outcomes)

which is
(365x364x363x...x356)/(365 raised to 10) lets call this **y**

**y** gives you the probability of all of them having different birthdays. The opposite of **y** is, two or more people have the same birthday.

SO **1-y** is your answer

**I calculated this as 0.1169 aka 11.69%**

Answer (score 1):

I think this is worth reading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem